# Using N threads or N-1 threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I've come across code that looks like this in more than one place in some code I have inherited:

```
const size_t N = 4;
FOO data[N];
boost::thread_group all_threads;
for(size_t i = 0; i < N-1; i++)
{
    all_threads.create_thread(processData, data[i]);
}
processData(data[N-1]);
all_threads.join_all();
```

For N tasks, create N-1 threads and do the last data item in the main thread. Ignoring issues about creating too many threads (N is always either 4 or 8) is there any merit in this rather than just creating N threads in the loop? From my perspective, having two different invocation methods for `processData` means two places to change if the parameters update, and reading the code there's the extra cognitive load to check that we really are doing the Nth call correctly.

Comment: This is really a matter of personal choice and app design. If the main thread is just going to sit idle on the join, then it makes sense to put it to work.  But if the main thread needs to do other things, then of course just create an extra processing thread so the main thread can do what it needs to do.

Comment: Guess it boils down to why create then join 4 threads when 3 is enough for the job.

Comment: Breaking a bad habit. You'd be amazed how many people write divide-and-conquer algorithms, for example, that, as they partition, launch two threads and *wait* vs launching one thread and *work*.

Comment: @WhozCraig but there's no significant execution time difference (as far as I am aware, given a sensible scheduler) in this case between waiting on four threads versus doing it once in the main thread then waiting if needed on the other three.

Comment: This should be wrapped in some code that is written only once that permits the call to `processData` to look the same whether it is dispatched to a thread or not. That will allow that code to re-use threads instead of constantly creating and terminating threads as well.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a thread has overhead. Thus, avoiding the creation of a thread has some merit.

Whether that merit is significant, depends on the use case. For small inputs, a single thread will be more optimal than a parallel implementation. For large inputs, the effect of creating a single thread will be insignificant. Between those extremes, there is likely to be an interval of input sizes where the creation of a single thread is significant. It may be a small interval.

Conclusion: Creating N threads for symmetric simplicity can be reasonable. If you measure that thread creation takes a significant portion of execution time, then consider the described N-1 technique or even single-threaded implementation.